# Por que não consigo adicionar um marcador ao clicar no mapa?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou utilizando este código:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static com.marcadorfixo.R.id.map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {
                googleMap.addMarker(
                        new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                );
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng uaua = new LatLng(-9.840318, -39.480388);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(uaua)
                .title("Uauá"));
    }
}
```

O Android Studio até chega a compilar, mas ao tentar executar o aplicativo ele simplesmente para de funcionar.

Comment: Qual erro apresentado pelo android studio?

Comment: Cara, ele não acusa erro, é isso que não entendo. Por exemplo: Ele compila, não acusa erro algum, aí quando vou executar o app ele para de funcionar. Tipo, se ele executasse e quando clicasse no mapa ele parasse eu mesmo poderia procurar o problema, mas nem isso... Já procurei alguns tutoriais, mas é escasso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está sendo que você está adicionando o click em um objeto `null` que não foi instanciado você só poderá adicionar o click após receber o objeto no método `onMapReady`. Tente a solução abaixo:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static com.marcadorfixo.R.id.map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    //GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng uaua = new LatLng(-9.840318, -39.480388);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(uaua)
                .title("Uauá"));

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {
                googleMap.addMarker(
                        new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo. Você resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado aí